# Does MongoDB Grails plugin support SSL

Tags: java, mongodb, grails, plugins, ssl

I am trying to configure my Grails application that uses MongoDB plugin for persistence. My application runs in the development environment, against default MongoDB installation.

In production I am using a MongoDB instance configured to use SSL. I am unable to connect to that database (not find any documentation regarding the SSL configuration). The plugin documentation does mention using MongoOptions. So I tried:

```
grails {
  mongo {
    ...
    options {
      socketFactory = SocketFactory.getDefault()
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Bean property 'socketFactory' is not writabe or has an invalid setter method
```

Without the options, the error is:

```
IOException authentication the connection
```

Does Grails MongDB plugin support SSL-based configuration?